# How can I put a vertical line down the center of a div?

Tags: css, html

How do I put a vertical line down the middle of a div? Maybe I should put two divs inside the div and put a left border on one and a right border on the other? I have a DIV tag and I need to put one ascx on the left (that will get swapped out from time to time with another ascx) and then a static ascx on the left. Any ideas on how I should do this? Maybe I answered my own question.

Any pointers would be great

Comment: just to check--you want two columns, one containing one ascx and the other containing another ascx, with a line separating both of them down the middle, right?

Comment: What's an ascx?

Answer (score 104):

Although this question was asked 9yrs ago and a lot of the answers would "work". CSS has evolved and you can now do it in a single line without using `calc`.

### One liner (2018) answer:

`background: linear-gradient(#000, #000) no-repeat center/2px 100%;`

#### How this works

1. `linear-gradient(#000, #000)` this creates a `background-image` so we can later use `background-size` to contain it.
2. `no-repeat` this stops the gradient from repeating when we do put `background-size` on it.
3. `center` - this is the `background-position` this is where we put the "diving line"
4. `/2px 100%` - this is making the image 2px wide and 100% of the element you put it in.

### This is the extended version:

```
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000, #000);
  background-size: 2px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
```

Comment: Works in ie11 too

Comment: In my solution, the line was matching a border from above. On the div where I put your solution, the line was off by 1px. I added this css rule at the end to fix it: background-position-x: calc(50% - 1px);

Comment: Would you be willing to drop this into a code snippet?

Comment: This is an oldie but goodie, worked great for a WP Gravity Form that would've required some serious rearranging to achieve what the UI designer wanted.

Answer (score 84):

Maybe this can help you

```css
.here:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px dotted #ff0000;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}

div {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center
}
```

```html
<div class="here">Content</div>
```

Here's is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HUN73R_13/sN2pt/1008/) demo.

Comment: Depending on how your css and DOM is set up, you may need to change `z-index: -1` to `z-index: 0`. If the divs and classes in this answer are visible in the developer console of your browser but the line isn't appearing, try that first.

Comment: You can replace `z-index:-1` with `pointer-events:none`, and keep the `:after` above anything

Answer (score 21):

Here's a more modern way to draw a line down a div. Just takes a little css:

```css
.line-in-middle {
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
   background: linear-gradient(to right, 
                               transparent 0%, 
                               transparent calc(50% - 0.81px), 
                               black calc(50% - 0.8px), 
                               black calc(50% + 0.8px), 
                               transparent calc(50% + 0.81px), 
                               transparent 100%); 
 }
```

```html
<div class="line-in-middle"></div>
```

Works in all modern browsers. http://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient

Comment: @Kamil Kiełczewski just want to give heads up to others cos on the link he provided says IE11 supported which is true but the code is not working.

Comment: @JerickAllanSernalDimaano works in IE 11 I have installed, 11.413.15063.0. What version are you seeing it not work in? What are you seeing?

Comment: @Samuel Neff, my IE version is 11.713.10586.0. Here's what I see: http://imgur.com/a/sffzK

Comment: @JerickAllanSernalDimaano interesting. I can get that to happen if I change the zoom setting on the webpage (ctrl-+) and it doesn't fix even if I set it back to 100% (not until refresh). Thanks for sharing the screenshot. IE sucks but we need to deal with it. :(

Answer (score 5):

Just tested this; works:

```
<div id="left" style="width:50%;float:left;background:green;">left</div>
<div id="right" style="margin-left:50%;border-left:solid 1px black;background:red;">right</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my version, a gradient middle line using `linear-gradient`

```css
.block {
      width:400px;
      height:200px;
      position:relative;
 }
.block:before {
      content:"";
      width:1px;
      height:100%;
      display:block;
      left:50%;
      position:absolute;
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #000, #fff);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #000, #fff);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #000, #fff);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #000, #fff);
      background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fff, #000, #fff);
 }
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Why do you use `:before` herein?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a wrapper div with a background image. If not, then you are not guaranteed to have the border go all the way from the top to the bottom.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>Float this one left</div>
    <div>float this one right</div>
</div>
```

*be sure to leave the space between the left and right for the image to show up.

you'll need a style that looks like:

```
.wrapper{background:url(img.jpg) 0 12px repeat-y;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your multiple DIV approach is going to be the sanest way to approach this:

```
<DIV>
   <DIV style="width: 50%; border-right: solid 1px black">
      /* ascx 1 goes here */
   </DIV>
   <DIV style="width: 50%">
      /* ascx 2 goes here */
   </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Comment: Just checked; unless you edit and add a float this doesn't work.

Comment: if the left is shorter than the right, then I don't think the border will span the entire height.

Answer (score 0):

Three divs?

```
<div>
   <div>
      /* ascx 1 goes here */
   </div>
   <div style="width:1px; background-color: #000"></div>
   <div>
      /* ascx 2 goes here */
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to ask your self one thing ... will it work when you dont have the same height on all internal div