# How do I draw a vertical line from the middle of this button?

Tags: html, css

I have got a button and I would like it to get a line when hovering over it and this line should start from the middle of the button.

In the end it should look like that:

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkaRx.png)

```css
.hotspot__btn {
  background-color: #ee2737;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 0.75px solid #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px #ee27384f;
  outline-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.hotspot__btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 12px #ee27384f;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="hotspot">
    <button class="hotspot__btn"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179928/how-can-i-put-a-vertical-line-down-the-center-of-a-div

Comment: how this line should look like ?

Comment: @Fifi thanks I will have a look at it

Comment: @ths it should just be a simple straight line which starts from the middle of my button

Comment: I see, to which way it should go on hover : left, right, top or bottom ?

Comment: @ths to the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pseudo element as the line. Positioning achieved with absolute positioning the line so the button needs `position: relative`.

```css
.hotspot__btn {
  background-color: #ee2737;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 0.75px solid #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px #ee27384f;
  outline-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 3;
  
  /* so we can position the line */
  position: relative;
}

.hotspot__btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 12px #ee27384f;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s linear;
}


.hotspot__btn:hover:before {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 300px;
  background: purple;
  
  /* positioning of line relative to the button */
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px; /* amount of padding top of your button */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="hotspot">
    <button class="hotspot__btn"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: oh thanks thanks that was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: *"whatever is needed"* Humm, and how did you know that `300px` is needed ? Anyway, we're just discussing nothing personal, thanks.

Comment: All good... In the absence of clearer visual guide I just took a guess based on my previous experience... why would they want a vertical line coming from a dot? Probably to connect to some other element...

Answer (score 1):

You should take useful of pseudo `after` element:

```css
  .hotspot { 
      margin: 25px;
    }
    
    .hotspot__btn {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #ee2737;
      border-radius: 50px;
      border: 0.75px solid #ffffff;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px #ee27384f;
      outline-style: none;
      padding: 5px;
      z-index: 3;
    }

    .hotspot__btn:hover {
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 12px #ee27384f;
      transition: box-shadow 0.5s linear;
      transition: all .2s ease-in-out


    }
    .hotspot__btn::after{ 
      content: '';
      width: 2px;
      height: 0;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      background-color: greenyellow;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      transition: all .2s ease-in-out
    }
    .hotspot__btn:hover::after{ 
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="hotspot">
      <button class="hotspot__btn"></button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the `:before` or the `:after` pseudo-element to act as a straight line :

```css
.hotspot__btn {
  position: relative; /** allows the :after to be positioned according to the button **/
  background-color: #ee2737;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 0.75px solid #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px #ee27384f;
  outline-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.hotspot__btn:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; /** allows a better control ove the line positionning **/
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0); /** centering the line horizontally **/
  background-color: #00f;
  transition: height .4s 0s ease;
}

.hotspot__btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 12px #ee27384f;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s linear;
}

.hotspot__btn:hover:after {
  height: 50%; /** from the middle to the bottom which is 50% of the button's height **/
}
```

```html
<div class="hotspot">
  <button class="hotspot__btn"></button>
</div>
```

If you want that line to stretch as the shadow of the `button`, you may use `calc` function to add the shadow's `spread-radius` which is `12px` to the `50%` of the `button`'s `height`.

```css
.hotspot__btn {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ee2737;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 0.75px solid #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px #ee27384f;
  outline-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.hotspot__btn:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
  background-color: #00f;
  transition: height .4s 0s ease;
}

.hotspot__btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 12px #ee27384f;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s linear;
}

.hotspot__btn:hover:after {
  height: calc(50% + 12px); /** adding 12px from the blur-radius of the box-shadow **/
}
```

```html
<div class="hotspot">
  <button class="hotspot__btn"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can look into using the pseudo-element `::after` and then styling it to fit your needs (I'm not sure what exactly you want this line to look like)

See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after).

Comment: i added a image where you see what it should like in the end